# Can you review my PHP created header?

Tags: php, optimization, header

So, I'm reading through the [YUI best practices for speeding up your web page](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html), and I'm using PHP to try and implement some of those suggestions. Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php 
// Expires one year from now
$expires = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"),   date("d"),   date("Y")+1);
// Format date
$date =  date('D, d M Y H:i:s', $expires);
// Send HTTP header
header("Expires: $date GMT");
if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip')) 
    ob_start("ob_gzhandler"); 
else 
    ob_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE ....
...
</head>
<?php flush(); ?>
<body>
...
```

So, does the above look good?

I have two specific questions.

1. Is the `ob_start();` after the `else` necessary.
2. If the `flush()` doing any good at all (or possibly harm?)

   One of the suggestions is that you [flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) your page, yet another suggestion is that you GZIP your page. It makes sense that [you can't flush a GZIPPED page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352759/php-flush-how-often-and-best-practises), since the whole page is one big bundle right?

   What happens if you use flush() on a page that is GZIPPED? Can anything "bad" happen? Should you keep flush() in your page for the benefit of browsers that don't accept GZIPPED content?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip')) 
    ob_start("ob_gzhandler"); 
else 
    ob_start();
```

You can simply write:

```
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
```

It will automatically determine whether the browser supports gzip/deflate ;)

And as you enabled Output Buffering your page will be flushed as a whole chunk, therefore `flush` will not have an effect. But it won't harm either. It simply will flush nothing ;)

Comment: @nikic - Thanks - re:Expires I create `$expires`, then I modify the format with `date()` and store it in `$date`, and I finally do send it with, `header("Expires: $date GMT")`

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see that ;)