# Output Text in PHP While Loop (while page is still working?)

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a simple php page, that is doing some operations for an mysql result set:

```
$i = $d = $n = 0;

$sql="SELECT record, field1,field2,field3 from table where condition='xxxx'" ;
result=$db->send_sql($sql);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  //about 500 results
  //now performing some actions on these results via function call
  $i++;
  if($row['field1'] == 'xxx')
  {
    $d++;
    echo $row['record'].": ";
    echo do_something(field1,field2); //function will echo some text
    echo "<br>";
  }
  else
  {
    $n++;
    echo $row['record'].": nothing to do <br>";
  }
}
echo "<hr>Total: ".$i." - Updates: ".$d." - Nothing done: ".$n;
```

All works, as it should but the Output/echos are only shown, once all operations have been done and the while statement has been worked through.

It might be a silly question, but is there a way to show the "echos/output" "on the fly" - so the user get's the "something is happening" experience?

Comment: If you're wanting it to dynamically update, then you should look at AJAX and long-polling.

Comment: Thanks Ram for correcting my typos  (shame on me ...)

Here's what worked for me, based on the answers below:
 
 echo str_repeat(" ", 256)."<br>\r\n";
 flush();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

echo sends the output toward the user immediately, but that output might be held up by a couple of layers in between.  If you want the feel you describe, use AJAX.  Otherwise, you can try some of these approaches:

- Turn [output buffering off](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php)
- [flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) immediately after sending your HTML head element
- then flush() periodically, with some str_repeat() to kickstart/prevent timeouts

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352759/php-flush-how-often-and-best-practises) and [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/faster-web-pages-php-buffer-flush/) conversation on performance/best practices and [this conversation on output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579116/how-to-flush-data-to-browser-but-continue-executing).

Answer (score 1):

PHP is run on the server and displays output to the client when it is finished.  I think you will need Javascript to do this, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `flush()` function to send data to browser after each loop execution.

Comment: Flush is the way to do it here, if you by any chance is using output buffering then adding an ob_flush() would be advised.

Comment: unfortunately the output will be visible once the whole script is finished so this is not solution